# I have a SQL Syntax error on my php page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, insert

Here is the mysql insert the I am running in php. I have removed the part giving the error but then I get a error on the next piece. I am not seeing what is diffrent to cause the error.

```
$fields="adv_exchange SET synum='".$synum."', worknum='".$_POST['worknum']."', user_id='".$current_user->ID."', f_name='".$current_user->user_firstname."', l_name='".$current_user->user_lastname."', email='".$current_user->user_email."', regnum=".$_POST['regnum'].", item='".$item."', qsver='".$_POST['qsver']."', flashrom='".$_POST['flashrom']."',expansion='".$_POST['board']."', rdisplay='". $_POST['rdisplay']."', screen_model='".$_POST['screen_model']."', p_hardware='".$_POST['cable']."', pcolor='".$_POST['pcolor']."', pname='".$_POST['pname']."', kboard='".$_POST['kboard']."', ip='".$_POST['ip']."', reg_name='".$_POST['reg_name']."', mem=".$_POST['mem'].", dt_server='".$_POST['dt_server']."', alert='".$_POST['alert']."', ows='".$_POST['ows']."', w_date='".$_POST['w_date']."', flashromver='".$_POST['flashromver']."', s_size='".$_POST['s_size']."', mag='".$_POST['mag']."', rcard='".$_POST['rcard']."', kvsid=".$_POST['kvsid'].", finger='".$_POST['finger']."', stand_alone='".$_POST['stand_alone']."', standards='".$_POST['standards']."', profile='".$_POST['profile']."', man_date='".$_POST['man_date']."', l_sn='".$_POST['l_sn']."', misc='".$_POST['misc']."', problem='".$_POST['problem']."'";
```

then $query = "insert into $fields";

I receive back

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' item='JS900CV', qsver='', flashrom='',expansion='', rdisplay='', screen_model='' at line 1
>   Blockquote

if I echo the $query I get this:

> insert into adv_exchange SET synum='SY5135', worknum='123456', user_id='2', f_name='REMOVED', l_name='REMOVED', email='REMOVED', regnum=, item='JS900CV', qsver='', flashrom='',expansion='', rdisplay='', screen_model='', p_hardware='', pcolor='', pname='', kboard='', ip='192.168.1.16', reg_name='', mem=, dt_server='', alert='', ows='', w_date='', flashromver='', s_size='', mag='', rcard='', kvsid=3, finger='', stand_alone='', standards='', profile='', man_date='', l_sn='', misc='misc test\r\n', problem='gen test'

Depending on what I enter in the error is changing spots in my statement. Not all fields are used the form is dynamic that is supplying the data so the fields are dependent on what options are selected. On a side note in case of concern about using `$_POST` to insert directly into mysql, I sanitize the array first. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a very, very bad approach to MySQL databases: manually creating the queries. You should really use prepared statements instead: this issue will be resolved as well.

Don't use `mysql_*` functions, use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead.

Your code would look like this (simplified):

```
// This holds the query
$statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO adv_exchange SET synum=?, worknum=?, etc=?, problem=?');

// This executes it with the given arguments. It's 100% injection-proof and safe. In fact, it's also faster.
$statement->execute(array($synum, $_POST['worknum'], $_POST['therest'], $_POST['problem']));
```

Comment: ok thank you that does look a lot easier to setup and maintain. Being safer is a bonus also thank you for the help.

Comment: Would this approach then get around sending empty fields that is causing my problem or would I still need to only send fields that are being used for that submission?

Comment: This approach will automatically insert empty strings, zeros or NULL values, depending on the POST data. No need to count for missing fields.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much. This will help me clean up a lot of my pages.

Answer (score 4):

Look at `regnum=,`. You don't provide a value for `regnum`. Either leave it out entirely or set it to an appropriate value.

Comment: So becuase there is no data in regnum it is giving the error? So I need to buil the insert statment without the empty fields then?

Comment: @new_to_this Yes, either omit the fields or provide a value.

Answer (score 0):

regnum=".$_POST['regnum']." is causing the problem.  When it is undefined, you get regnum=, in the SQL query

A bigger concern is that you are not escaping your inputs.  Either use mysql_real_escape_string around them, or better, use prepared statements.

Comment: I have a function I am running against the $_POST array before my query: That runs mysql_real_escape_string, stripes out jave, html, and style tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to SET regnum=SOMETHING.

Currently it's empty.